# Custom map marker graphical bug on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developping a google map with custom marker on it and it work very well on most of devices.

The problem is that a graphical bug appears on some device, mostly touchscreen devices. Actually we can see the image used for the marker in a bigger size and half transparent on the right of the markers (see in red circle on image). I liked to remove those images from the map, how can I do that ?

[image]

The image used for the custom marker is 256*134 and I create my marker like this :

```
        markerToday.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: latitudes[j], lng: longitudes[j]},
            icon: {
                url: icons['Today'].icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(256, 134),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(64, 67),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(128, 67),
                labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(99, 15)
            },
            label: {
                text: formattedTime_array,
                fontSize: '17px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana',
                color: 'white'
            },
            map: map
        }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by chaging the original size of the icon used. Now, instead of (256, 134), I directly use an image of the size of the desired marker (128, 67).